# WCF Security error with VS 2008 Unit Test

Tags: .net, wcf, unit-testing, authentication

I was running my first Visual Studio 2008 Unit Test with a WCF Service and I received the following error:

> Test method
>   UnitTest.ServiceUnitTest.TestMyService
>   threw exception: 
>   System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException:
>   The HTTP request is unauthorized with
>   client authentication scheme
>   'Anonymous'. The authentication header
>   received from the server was
>   'Negotiate,NTLM'. ---> 
>   System.Net.WebException: The remote
>   server returned an error: (401)
>   Unauthorized..

I am also getting the following failed audit in the security log:

> Logon Failure:    Reason: The user has
>   not been granted the requested logon
>   type at this machine
>      User
>   Name: (Internet Guest Account)
>  
>   Domain:        
>       Logon Type:    3
>   
>  Logon Process: IIS 
>   Authentication Package:   
>   MICROSOFT_AUTHENTICATION_PACKAGE_V1_0
>   Workstation Name:

I am hosting the WCF service in IIS 6.0 on a Windows XP SP3 machine.  I have both the "Anonymous Access" and "Integrated Windows authentication" checked for the WCF service virtual directory.

Here is my config file for the service:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="MyBinding">
               <security mode="None" />
           </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
            <customBinding>
                <binding name="MyBinding">
               <transactionFlow />
                    <textMessageEncoding />
                    <httpsTransport authenticationScheme="Ntlm"/>
                </binding>
            </customBinding>
            <wsHttpBinding>
                <binding name="MyBinding">
                   <security mode="None" />
               </binding>
            </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <service 
            behaviorConfiguration="Service1Behavior"
            name="Service1"
        >
            <endpoint 
                address="" 
                binding="wsHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="MyBinding"
                contract="IService1"
            >
                <identity>
                    <dns value="localhost" />
                   </identity>
            </endpoint>
        </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="Service1Behavior">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                   <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
               </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had to change the following IIS and WCF service configurations to get past the "Negotiate,NTLM" exception.

IIS Configurations:

> -- Unchecked "Anonymous Access" checkbox and check the "Integrated
>   Windows authentication" checkbox in
>   the directory security setting for the
>   WCF Service virtual directory.

WCF Services:

> -- implemented basicHttpBinding and configured the basicSettingBinding
>   security setting to
>   "TransportCredentialsOnly" mode and
>   TransportClientCredentialType to
>   "Windows"

Here is my updated wcf service configuration:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="windowsBasicHttpBinding">
                <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
                </security>
            </binding>
       </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
        <service    
      behaviorConfiguration="CityOfMesa.ApprovalRouting.WCFService.RoutingServiceBehavior"
           name="CityOfMesa.ApprovalRouting.WCFService.RoutingService"
        >
            <endpoint 
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="windowsBasicHttpBinding"
                name="basicEndPoint"    
                contract="CityOfMesa.ApprovalRouting.WCFService.IRoutingService" 
            />
        </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior 
                name="CityOfMesa.ApprovalRouting.WCFService.RoutingServiceBehavior"
            >
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
           </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: @alhambraeidos - I am not sure what you are trying to ask about the `RoutingServiceBehavior`

Answer (score 2):

When you have securityMode="None" in your binding, you should turn off integrated authentication.

Comment: I tried that and received the following error when I tried to update the service reference in the test project: Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved ''.  The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'.  The authenication header received from the ser

Comment: Can you browse to the WSDL? If you disable integrated authentication and enable anonymous authentication and have SecurityMode="None" on both the client and the server, it should work.

Comment: Check out the local security policy on the machine and make sure that anonymous users aren't locked out from network access. Most likely, the issue is in the AD group policy or local security policy for the machine.

Comment: I also ran this service in a web application and console application and received the same "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized" for both tests.

Answer (score 1):

The default authentication is windows (or NTLM) so you'll need to specify that you don't want authentication in your config file.

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <wsHttpBinding>
      <binding name="myBinding">
        <security mode="None" />
      </binding>
  </bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
```

also add this attribute to the endpoint

```
bindingConfiguration="myBinding"
```

The binding element specifies modifications of the standard behavior of the wsHttpBinding.

Then the "bindingConfiguration="myBinding" attribute on the endpoint says that that endpoint should use the modifications we specified.

Comment: Updated to security mode None

Comment: Still does not work....I even added the bindingName attribute to the service node.

Comment: k, tried with message security on and credentials none.
Also lowered my certainty that the solution will work

Comment: Also added the bindingConfiguration attribute to add to the endpoint element

Comment: When I tried to update the service reference, I got the following message: "The servrice certificate is not provided.  Specify a service certificate in ServiceCredentials"

Comment: I removed the bindingConfiguration attribute and I did not received that error from the previous comment

Comment: k, try setting the security back to none and include the bindingConfiguration in the endpoint element

Comment: should I set bingingConfiguration to "MyBinding"?

Comment: yes, (well, to "myBinding"). That can be changed to something more appropriate as long as it matches in both places

Comment: I am still getting the same error.  I have updated the source code to match your input

Answer (score 0):

As a side note.....There was a GPO setting "NTLM Authentication Level" that was controls authenication that was causing the unit test to generate the "Negotiate,NTLM" exception.